# Limiting how often a user can post on a particular person's profile/wall in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone

How can I limit a user to only to being able to post once or twice per day on a particular users's wall? I primarily want to do it in order to limit spam. My code for the wall, models, view, and controllers are below. I don't really know how to go about it as I'm new to rails but I know there is something time.now. I'm not exactly sure how to implement such a feature.

```
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @first_name = @user.first_name
 @last_name = @user.last_name
 @wallpost = WallPost.new(params[:wall_post])
 @showwallposts = @user.received_wallposts
end

def create
 @wallpost = WallPost.create(params[:wall_post])
end
```

models

```
class WallPost < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :content, :receiver_id, :sender_id
 belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
 belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :sent_wallposts, :class_name => 'WallPost', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'  
 has_many :received_wallposts, :class_name =>'WallPost', :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'
```

in the view

```
<%= form_for(@wallpost, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :receiver_id, :value => @user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :sender_id, :value => current_user.id %>    
  <%= f.text_area :content, :class => 'inputbox' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'right btn' %>    
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create [a custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators) which assures maximum `DAILY_LIMIT` posts have been created on that person's wall that day by that user:

```
class SpamValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  DAILY_LIMIT = 2

  def validate(record)
    if similar_posts_today(record).count >= DAILY_LIMIT
      record.errors[:spam_limit] << 'Too many posts today!'
    end
  end

  def similar_posts_today(record)
    WallPost.where(receiver: record.receiver, sender: record.sender)
            .where("DATE(created_at) = DATE(:now)", now: Time.now)
  end
end
```

Then add that validation to your `WallPost` model:

```
validates_with SpamValidator
```

Then it will fail with a validation error when trying to create a wall post beyond the limit set in the constant. You need to handle this case in the `create` action in your controller. A simple (but not optimal in terms of user experience) way of handling this is:

```
def create
  @wallpost = WallPost.new(params[:wall_post])

  flash[:error] = "You've reached the daily posting limit on that wall." unless @wallpost.save

  redirect_to user_path(@wallpost.receiver)
end
```

With that, it'll try to save the new wall post, if it is unable to, it'll set `flash[:error]` to the error message above. You'd need to show this on your `show.html.erb` page with `<%= flash[:error] if flash[:error] %>`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Really appreciate it. I never heard of the validator. Learned a lot from your solution.

Comment: by the way, "if similar_posts_today(record).count > DAILY_LIMIT" should be "if similar_posts_today(record).count >= DAILY_LIMIT" in order to enforce the limit. Thanks again. I really appreciate it. Just letting you know in case you want to modify your post for other users who might stumble upon it.